# Sending file size over Tcp socket

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, integer

Hello  i am using  Ms visual studio 2015.The problem is when i am sending file size  to  server socket. N holds the  int value of the file size.What is wrong with the code ?  The code is :

```
    int size = htonl(n);
    send(sock, &size, sizeof(size),0);
```

and the error i get is : 
argument of type   "int  *" is incompatible with parameter of  type
"const char *"

Comment: `send(sock, (const char*)&size, sizeof(size), 0);`?

Comment: I always forget that reading such data with `char*` is not UB. that should be correct

Answer (score 1):

If you see e.g. [this `send` reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740149(v=vs.85).aspx) you will see that it takes a `const char *` argument for the data. When you use `&size` you create a pointer to an `int`, i.e. `int *`. Those two types are not implicitly convertible between each other.

You need to cast the pointer to the correct type:

```
send(sock, reinterpret_cast<char*>(&size), sizeof(size),0);
```